Is this matroid is graphic?
Given an matroid $M=(E=\{1,2,3\},\mathcal{I}=\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\})$, is this matroid graphic?
I know that graph (not necessarily simple) with 3 edges has these choices which are in follows:

I know the matroid of (5),(6)  are isomorphic, $M_{G}(5)\cong M_{G}(6)=M$ so the matroid $M=(E=\{1,2,3\},\mathcal{I}=\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\})$ is graphic?
I think my thought maybe something wrong but I have no words to say why, can you check my ideas and gives me some supports? Thanks!

Yes, this is graphic. Moreover, there are other choices than just (5) and (6), for example (7, with relabeling $e_2 \iff e_3$) and (12) have the same matroid structure.

Also, to me it seems that there's one graph on 3 edges missing from the list, a graph similar to (12) but the loop is on the middle vertex.

@RandyMarsh， Yes, drawing pictures takes some time. I've just listed a part of them. The pictures needed for the questions I want to ask are already included in the ones above. Anyway, thank you very much for clearing up my doubts. I sincerely hope that you can continue to help me. Thank you.

Ah, I thought the list was from some textbook, it looks very nice :)
